# Unassigned local variables

Tags: c#

I bet these types of questions are the most common, however after trying what it said in a few other questions and still getting errors, I came here. I'm getting the following errors:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'nodeRss'
>   Use of unassigned local variable 'nodeChannel'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XmlTextReader rssReader;
        XmlDocument rssDoc;
        XmlNode nodeRss;
        XmlNode nodeChannel;
        String title;
        String text;
        HttpWebRequest http = WebRequest.Create("http://www.aerolitegaming.com/login/login") as HttpWebRequest;
        http.KeepAlive = true;
        http.Method = "POST";
        http.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postData="login=SNIP&register=0&password=SNIP&remember=1&cookie_check=0&redirect=forum%2F&_xfToken=";
        byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        int y = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;
        http = WebRequest.Create("http://www.aerolitegaming.com/forum") as HttpWebRequest;
        http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        http.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
        http.AllowAutoRedirect=false;
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        rssReader = new XmlTextReader("http://aerolitegaming.com/forums/in-game-reports.132/index.rss");
        rssDoc = new XmlDocument();
        rssDoc.Load(rssReader);
        // Loop for the <rss> tag
        for (int i = 0; i < rssDoc.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            // If it is the rss tag
            if (rssDoc.ChildNodes[i].Name == "rss")
            {
                // <rss> tag found
                nodeRss = rssDoc.ChildNodes[i];
            }
        }
        // Loop for the <channel> tag
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeRss.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            // If it is the channel tag
            if (nodeRss.ChildNodes[i].Name == "channel")
            {
                // <channel> tag found
                nodeChannel = nodeRss.ChildNodes[i];
            }
        }
        // Set the labels with information from inside the nodes
        title = "Title: " + nodeChannel["title"].InnerText;
        text = "Description: " + nodeChannel["description"].InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(title);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  You're using the variable when you have potentially not assigned it a value.  You can't do that.

Comment: You're not setting those variables to anything before using them. It's like trying to do `int i; int j = i + 5;` Well, what is it supposed to add 5 to? No idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you assign these variables values in a different scope {    }.

To prevent the messages, simply give them values.

```
 XmlNode nodeRss = null;
 XmlNode nodeChannel = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `nodeRss` variable is an assigned in an `if` statement here:

```
if (rssDoc.ChildNodes[i].Name == "rss")
{
     // <rss> tag found
     nodeRss = rssDoc.ChildNodes[i];
}
```

I'm sure that you never fail to get into that if statement, and so you aren't worried about the lack of initialization. However, the compiler doesn't know that, and so is complaining that `nodeRss` is never assigned (because it isn't guaranteed to be).

In reality, I highly doubt you are actually guaranteed to get into that if statement, and so you should assign it a default value (null is ok) and check against that value before using the variable.

`nodeChannel` is running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the you are only assigning values to the two variables under certain conditions, which would lead to them not being set if those conditions have not been met.